# Cannot upgrade gsutil to 4.12

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm going to move several terabytes of data from a DRA bucket onto a Nearline bucket and I wish to utilize the new [Rewrite API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite), which I understand [requires](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-announce/gZ4EvHoZns8) gsutil 4.12:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-dra-bucket/* gs://my-nearline-bucket/
```

But even after having run `gcloud components update`, I'm still on gsutil 4.11. Is there any other way to update to gsutil 4.12?

I'm on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Cloud SDK incorporates updates to the underlying tools approximately every 2 weeks, so if you are attempting to update to a recently created release / pre-release of gsutil it may not yet be available via the Cloud SDK.

You can get a copy of newest gsutil from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gsutil).